# Migrating from PyStan2 to PyStan3

Tags: python, stan, pystan

The following Python code assumes the usage of pystan 2. However, when running it with pystan 3, it raises an error stating that algorithm='Fixed_param' is unknown. In the case of pystan 3, what modifications are required apart from changing import pystan to import stan and pystan.StanModel to stan.build?

```
import stan

with open('ben_files.stan', 'r') as f:
    ben = f.read()

data_list = {'n': 100, 'p': M, 'c': N, 'k': r}
posterior = stan.build(model_code=ben)
fit = posterior.sample(data=data_list)
```

What other modifications are necessary for using pystan 3 instead of pystan 2, apart from the ones mentioned above (import statements and replacing pystan.StanModel with stan.build)?

Answer (score 0):

> What other modifications are necessary for using pystan 3 instead of pystan 2

The PyStan docs provide a useful "Upgrading to v3" document [here](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrading.html#notable-changes). The "Notable changes" section is particularly helpful, which I duplicate here for convenience (with some minor rewording for clarity):

- Use `import stan` instead of `import pystan`.
- `data` and `random_seed` must now be passed at compile time, to the `.build()` method. Previously these values were passed at `.sampling()` time.
- Use `num_samples` to indicate number of desired draws, instead of `iter`.
- Use `fit["param"]` instead of `fit.extract()["param"]`. The shape of the array returned will be different.
- Draws are returned in a shape which reflects their shape in the Stan model. Number of draws is the trailing index.
- The "stansummary" display is no longer supported. Support for displaying effective sample size is planned. In the meanwhile, you may wish to look into the [`arviz`](https://python.arviz.org/en/stable/) package, in particular, note `arviz.summary()`, which still reports ESS (bulk and tail) and Rhat.
- The `check_hmc_diagnostics()` function is removed. Support for plugins has been added to allow for the development of a replacement. The function was removed from PyStan because it is not part of the Stan C++ library.
- Microsoft Windows is not supported in PyStan3. It was (partially) supported in PyStan 2.
- The default, recommended HMC sampler is fully supported. *Variational inference, maximization algorithms, and other sampling algorithms are not supported*. Users who need these features should consider using different software (e.g., CmdStan, CmdStanPy, jax, PyTorch).

I also found there were a number of changes I needed to make when migrating from PyStan2 to PyStan3, which *weren't* indicated in the "Notable changes" section, namely:

- The `.sampling()` method has been replaced by `.sample()` (you've already made this change in your example code)
- The `.StanModel()` function has been replaced by `.build()` (again, you've already noted this one in your example).
- Values in the `data` dictionary passed to `.build()` can no longer be `pandas.Series` objects (use `.to_numpy()` method in any data preparation steps)
- Models can no longer be passed as filepaths at the compile step, and instead have to be loaded separately and passed as a string (ie. the `file` argument of `StanModel()` has not been ported to `.build()`)
- Introduction of `asyncio` events breaks PyStan in Jupyter Notebooks. If you wish to use PyStan3 in Jupyter notebooks you should use [nest-asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/). This is documented [in this FAQ](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-pystan-with-jupyter-notebook-or-jupyterlab).